# A simple Employee database in C

Tags: database, structure

i want to make an Employee database program, as far as i can program im just a beginner and i dont know how to do some parts. For example, id like to monitor the work time of workers, and i dunno how exactly do so i can view all of the workers hours, for example, i did the basics with structures so i have a structure with a field for names  and int for all of the hours he worked. But how do i see his ,,history" Which day he worked for how long? Either i dunno how to dynamically change the structure co i can delete or modify days. Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading through a few database tutorials. You will probably be fine starting out with sqlite as the db of choice as long as you don't need concurrent write.

Comment: Would you care to recommend some ?

Comment: I'd suggest either the free udemy [Learn Database Design with MySQL](https://www.udemy.com/learn-database-design-with-mysql/) or the more [in-depth tutorial on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tutorial-step-database-design-sql-david-mccaldin), or if those don't strike your fancy check google for 'learn how to make datagbases with C'
There are thousands of phenomenal tutorials, how-to's, and free courses.